# Cutting a text file from line containing X to first line containing Y

Tags: bash, shell, filter, sed, awk

I have many text files containing bank transactions in the middle of them.

Each file has a custom header of variable length.

In every file, transactions begin exactly after the first (and only) line containing the text:

```
FECHA OPERACION FECHA VALOR CONCEPTO    IMPORTE SALDO
```

In every file, transactions end exactly before the first (and only) line containing the text:

```
PROCHAIN
```

Each line after the "frontier" is a transaction, one transaction per line, until the closing guard.

There is a single block of transactions per file.

How can I conveniently and efficiently extract all transactions using command line tools only?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sed '1,/FECHA/d;/PROCHAIN/,$d' inputfile
```

Comment: @Robottinosino: Yes, that's how it works. To accommodate white space and anchor the pattern: `/^[[:blank:]]*FECHA/` (you can make the text longer, I just used the beginning for brevity)

Comment: PERFECTION. So elegant, so succinct, so powerful. LOVE it.

Comment: I rolled back the edit because it was largely incorrect.